# Player Save State for Game Mode

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

On our server I'd like to switch people to adventure when they enter an area, but when they leave it should set them back to the game mode they were in before entering.

So my question is, is it possible to record player information in the scoreboard or a tag for their game mode and then use it later

e.g. `tag @s add GameMode=[m]`

Comment: First question is "Can I query the game mode of a player?" and I think the answer is yes.  Then it's just a matter of saving the result of that query to a scoreboard objective for the player, which shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When they enter the area do:

```
/tag @a[m=s] add survival
```

And:

```
/tag @a[m=c] add creative
```

And:

```
/tag @a[m=a] add adventure
```

Then just change their gamemodes back later accordingly:

```
/gamemode a @a[tag=adventure,r=5]
```

etc.

Make sure to untag them:

```
/tag @a[tag=survival,r=5] remove survival
```